# Nextcloud does do not launch at reboot/restart session (autostart) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, autostart, nextcloud

I want to have Nextcloud start when I open my session. Following the [instructions to start applications automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) does not work for me; I have to start Nextcloud manually each time I start my session.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Nextcloud client 2.6.5

*Edit: clicking the option in the  Nextcloud Client General Settings did not work*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My way to add a program on user session startup is firstly install gnome-tweaks.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then run it from activity menu, and go top **Startup program**, click on the **+** to add a new program, then choose **Nextcloud** from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be under the Nextcloud Client General Settings. Click the box to put a check on the option to "Launch on System Startup"

Comment: did not work for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you do it as root.
For me, all I had to do is add the user who started up the system to the sudoers:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo <user_who_started_the_system>
```

Have a look at: https://devconnected.com/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-on-ubuntu-20-04
to get some more instructions.